# What is the Discrete Time Fourier Transform of $x[n] = \frac{3\sin{(3\pi\frac{n}{4})}}{\pi n}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

$$x[n] = \frac{3\sin{(3\pi\frac{n}{4})}}{\pi n}$$

What is the Discrete Time Fourier Transform $X(e^{jw})$  of $x[n]$?

Thanks.

I need to plot a graph of $X(e^{jw})$ for the sinc function x[n].
I know it is a rectangular waveform.....

Comment: DT? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @J. M.: I'm guessing it's the discrete FT, i.e. for $N$ points $\{f(k) | k = 0,\ldots,N-1 \},$, you get $$f(n) \mapsto \sum_k e^{-2\pi i nk/N} f(k).$$

Comment: @Gerben : I think it is DTFT but not DFT.

Comment: I'm asking because OP **should** have supplied what formula he's supposed to use, sign/normalization and all...

Comment: I need to plot a graph of $X(e^{jw})$ for the sinc function x[n].

Comment: @zingsi123  You should consider transferring this question to the newly established site dsp.stackexchange.com for digital signal processing.

Comment: The $x(n)$ $\ (n\in{\mathbb Z})$ are the Fourier coefficients of a certain $2\pi$-periodic function $X(\cdot)$. The problem consists in finding an expression for $X(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\dfrac{\sin \omega_c n}{\pi n}\Longleftrightarrow \text{rect}\left(\dfrac{\omega}{2\omega_c}\right)$$
which is a rectangular function from $-\omega_c$ to $\omega_c$.